# How to define our type object like dict,list, set

Tags: python

If we typing in interpreter "[]" or "{}" it returns a list or dict types.For example:

```
>>>{}
{}
>>>type({})
<class 'dict'>
x=[]
type(x)
<class 'list'>
```

So how we can define our patterns like our objects.Fox ex:

```
#Its just example , this won't work in your ide .
>>>type(<>)
<class 'MyClass'>
```

How? or Possible? I think yes , because Python itself does it.

Comment: Short answer, you cannot (unless you modify and compile an specific distribution of python).

Comment: It invokes then some builtin magic right?

Comment: If getting class name is primary focus then `obj.__class__.__name__` should do it.

Comment: They are parsed by the interpreter.

Comment: ravirajaits its not clear.Can you show it with example that what is mean?

Answer (score 5):

The `[]` and `{}` syntaxes are specially defined by the [Python grammar](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/grammar.html), specifically in the [enclosure](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#grammar-token-enclosure) grammar element.

You cannot modify the Python grammar without actually modifying the `python` program. This is true across most languages; almost none of them will let you add to the grammar like this.

Answer (score 0):

when you type {} in your terminal then you create a dictionary object. when you type [] then you create a list object. when you check a type of list object then it return you 'list'. when you check type of dictionary object then it returns you dict. seems logical, does not it?

there is no option in python such as <> to create an object out of it that is defined in python.

similarly for e.g. tuple.

i think you need to complete basic lesson on Python object types first before you progress further.

Comment: I completed 70-80% of python actually.But I just wonder maybe have another way that i don't konw about.Thanks.

Comment: are you sure about it? are you sure you know 80% of Python funcionality? do you know e.g. python collections, python itertools and python functools?

Comment: Yes sure.I know coroutine , requestlib ,threads , multiprocessing so.etc.It's just simple question.Estensially I knew this..I just wondered maybe have a  way.

Comment: @GünelResulova I wouldn't be surprised if even Guido didn't know 70% of Python functionality including all the common libraries. You might have completed 70% of a course in Python, but I don't think you know 70% of Python functionality, especially if you don't know about Python's grammar and parsing rules.

Comment: yes because i started Python with libraries))I still  saw grammar today yet.